# Loading a new FXML file in the same scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, scene, fxmlloader

I'm new to JavaFX and i have a little problem with the UI.
I'm using JavaFX 8 and want to create my UI with FXML files.

I have created a pane with a header, a menubar and the placeholder for the content (This is the place where i want to load the others FXML files in when i press a Button from the menu bar). The content area is a AnchorPane.

I have tryed it with this:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane aContent;

@FXML
protected void test(ActionEvent event) {
    aContent.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load("view/ezMovieContent.fxml"));
}
```

The AnchorPane aContent is the content area in my scene. When i use this code i always get the message on the load() method

> The method load(InputStream) in the type FXMLLoader is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Thank you for your help,

With regards, Timo

Comment: @fabian i tryed it with an URL:
'URL myURL = new URL("view/ezmovieContent.fxml"); 
aContent.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(myURL));'
But now i get an error on the 'setAll()' argument: 
The method setAll(Node[]) is ambiguous for the type ObservableList<Node>

Comment: You get the error because the method `load()` in `FXMLLoader` does not take a string. (See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html).) The `static` method you are trying to reference takes a `URL`, so you need to pass it a URL.

Comment: @James_D ok. i tryed it with a URL, but now i have an error on the '.setAll()' arguement. The code looks like this: '  URL myURL = new URL("view/ezmovieContent.fxml"); 
  aContent.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(myURL));' and the errormessage is The method setAll(Node[]) is ambiguous for the type ObservableList<Node>

Comment: Either put the result of `load(...)` into a variable before calling `setAll(...)`, or use `setAll(FXMLLoader.<Node>load(myURL));`

Comment: @James_D I'm using the same code but I'm getting no protocol exception. `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Checking.fxml`